# Is there a way to schedule AbInitio Graph using an input pset with cron?

Tags: ab-initio

Pretty much as the title implies. With an AbInitio Graph, is there a way to use a cron expression in an input pset? What would need to be set up for the cron expression to be recognized and kick off the process?

Answer (score 0):

in AbInitio it's called "Control Center" -- you have to use it in order to schedule one time and/or reoccurring tasks